# How to install kernel 4.8 in RHEL?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, amazon-web-services, kernel

I am using RHEL vm provided by aws. I want to downgrade kernel 4.8 to for research purposes. Is there any way to do that? The result of `uname -r` is
 `5.14.0-162.12.1.el9_1.x86_64`
i tried converting to deb packages to rpm provided from url [for ubuntu](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-linux-kernel-4-8-ubuntu-16-04-16-10)

and i converted to rpm packages and tried to install

```
$ sudo yum install linux*4.8*.rpm 
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:24:43 ago on Tue 31 Jan 2023 07:17:30 AM UTC.
Package linux-headers-4.8.0-040800-4.8.0-40801.201610022.noarch is already installed.
Package linux-image-4.8.0-040800-generic-4.8.0-40801.201610022.x86_64 is already installed.
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.1.0.0()(64bit) needed by linux-headers-4.8.0-040800-generic-4.8.0-40801.201610022.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.1.0.0(OPENSSL_1.0.0)(64bit) needed by linux-headers-4.8.0-040800-generic-4.8.0-40801.201610022.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

but not working can you guys help me?

Comment: You cannot willy nilly take packages from alien distros and expect it to work. Sometimes you can mangle it to be accepted, but for kernels... I would never even try. I suggest you download the source, compile it then install it, if you can.